# Timer simulation in C?

Tags: c, time, timer

How can I use `<time.h>` to start and end a simulation after predefined period of time?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   int s;
   time_t t;

   srand((unsigned) time(&t));
   s=(rand()%4)+1;
   printf("%d" s);

   return 0;
}
```

After random generator of a variable `s`, I want to start a simulation that will end after `s` seconds. The number of simulations is processed (for each, `s` is generated), and the user terminates the program.

Comment: What do you simulate? What would your simulation actually do? Show some graphics? Compute a physical state (e.g. position of planets)?

Comment: Your question is very confused. You should **edit your question** to explain a lot more about your simulation.

Comment: Probably a bit rough, but you *could* just do `alarm(s);` and wait ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Read first [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) *carefully* (and follow all the references there!). You might want to have some [*event loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around some multiplexing call such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). You also should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get some broader view.

You probably should make a big difference between simulated time and elapsed real time (and CPU time).

Of course `<time.h>` is only relevant to get the time (and show it). You probably need more (and it is operating system specific; I guess you are using Linux).

You could organize your simulation as many small steps (in some event loop).